# lattice droplet using config server and eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

### What do I need to do to get my droplet (myapp) to get its configurations from the correct service at configserver.local.lattice.cf?

I'm able to deploy redis, mysql, eureka and the configserver.

I had to deploy the configserver with --privileged in order to user our git repository because it couldn't create /target/config directory.

Now I'm trying to deploy our application.

```
$ ltc --version
ltc version v0.6.0-34-g32acfa9 (diego 0.1434.0)
```

I deployed the images using the examples here: http://lattice.cf/docs/docker-image-examples/

```
ltc create mysql mysql --memory-mb 512 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --tcp-route 3306:3306
...
ltc list
------------------------------= Apps =-------------------------------
App Name    Instances   DiskMB      MemoryMB    Route
configserver    1/1     0       512     configserver.local.lattice.cf => 8888, configserver-8888.local.lattice.cf => 8888
eureka      1/1     0       512     eureka.local.lattice.cf => 8761, eureka-8761.local.lattice.cf => 8761
mysql       1/1     0       512     local.lattice.cf:3306 => 3306
redis       1/1     0       256     local.lattice.cf:6379 => 6379

------------------------------= Tasks =------------------------------
No tasks to display.
```

I can see in the eureka dashboard (eureka.local.lattice.cf) that the configserver has been registered:

```
Instances currently registered with Eureka

Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
CONFIGSERVER    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.11.11
```

I can also request my configurations from the configserver (configserver.local.lattice.cf/myapp/env)

```
{"name":"myapp","profiles":["env"],"label":"master","propertySources":[{"name":"overrides","source":{"eureka.instance.nonSecurePort":"${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8080}}}","eureka.instance.hostname":"${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}","eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone":"http://eureka.local.lattice.cf/"}}
...
```

I create the droplet, which is a spring-boot app, with this command:

```
ltc build-droplet myapp java -p ./target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --env spring.cloud.config.uri=http://configserver.local.lattice.cf
Uploading application bits...
Uploaded.
Submitted build of myapp
01/06 15:43:38.08 [BUILD|0] Successfully created container
01/06 15:43:39.49 [DROPLET|0] Deleted http://local.lattice.cf:8444/blobs/myapp/bits.zip.
01/06 15:43:39.50 [DROPLET|0] Exit status 0
01/06 15:43:39.55 [BUILD|0] Exit status 0
01/06 15:43:43.90 [BUILD|0] -----> Java Buildpack Version: ab72dd5 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#ab72dd5
01/06 15:45:06.41 [BUILD|0] -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_65 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_65.tar.gz (1m 22s)
01/06 15:45:07.47 [BUILD|0]        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.0s)
01/06 15:45:09.34 [BUILD|0] -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (1.8s)
01/06 15:45:09.38 [BUILD|0]        Memory Settings: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64M -Xss568K -Xms54613K -XX:MetaspaceSize=64M -Xmx54613K
01/06 15:45:12.03 [BUILD|0] -----> Downloading Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (2.6s)
01/06 15:45:21.94 [BUILD|0] Exit status 0
01/06 15:45:22.36 [DROPLET|0] Uploaded /tmp/droplet to http://local.lattice.cf:8444/blobs/myapp/droplet.tgz.
01/06 15:45:22.36 [DROPLET|0] Exit status 0
01/06 15:45:22.46 [DROPLET|0] Uploaded /tmp/result.json to http://local.lattice.cf:8444/blobs/myapp/result.json.
01/06 15:45:22.50 [DROPLET|0] Exit status 0
Build completed
```

Things look good so far right?  Using this env provides the same results:

```
--env CONFIG_SERVER_URL=http://configserver.local.lattice.cf
```

When I try to launch the droplet using:

```
ltc launch-droplet myapp myapp
```

It fails to connect to the configuration server:

```
01/06 15:55:52.22 [APP|0] 2016-01-06 21:55:52.213  INFO 13 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
01/06 15:55:52.77 [APP|0] 2016-01-06 21:55:52.773  WARN 13 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/myapp/cloud":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Passing --env CONFIG_SERVER_URL or --env spring.cloud.config.uri are simply not working for me with droplets.  However, using the bootstrap.yml with a droplet works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of my issue was that I didn't realize that the "cloud" profile was active when launching droplets with lattice (ltc).

In order for me to get my expected results, I had to update my cloud profiles in both the "myapp" configurations AND the default "applications" yaml file that I had setup.